# Can a PHP script continue running after ending the HTTP request?

Tags: php, http, scripting, webserver

How do I write a PHP script that continues running, even after flushing out some text and ending the HTTP request? Is this possible?

Comment: See the answer from [PHP Background Processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265073/php-background-processes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run PHP app forever or until php terminates

```
ignore_user_abort(true);

set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Seems unsafe if the page is requested frequently, the server could have large number of processes that are doing nothing.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested by the [`ignore_user_abort`](http://php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort) configuration directive, and/or the [`ignore_user_abort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function :

> Sets whether a client disconnect
>   should cause a script to be aborted.

Using this, you could :

- generate the part of the page that has to be sent to the browser
- flush the output, with [`flush`](http://php.net/flush) and/or [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)
- call `ignore_user_abort` *(either now or before)*
- do some more work

The user's browser will probably still indicate "waiting" or "loading", but the content of the page will be loaded and displayed -- and even if the user presses "stop", your script should continue its execution.

For more informations, there is an example on the manual's page of that function -- and you can take a look at this article : [How to Use `ignore_user_abort()` to Do Processing Out of Band](http://waynepan.com/2007/10/11/how-to-use-ignore_user_abort-to-do-process-out-of-band/)

Of course, while this can be used for some light process *(like "cleaning up" stuff at the end of a page, while displaying it as fast as possible to the user)*, you'll still be limited by `max_execution_time` and the like.

So, this is not a solution that should be used for long/heavy calculations.