# Can a PHP script abort itself or detect abortion?

Tags: php, http, scripting, webserver, abort

PHP scripts can [continue executing after the HTTP page request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428340/can-a-php-script-continue-running-after-ending-the-http-request), so how do I finally stop it executing when I'm done with it?

Also, is there an event to detect when the OS is going to forcibly abort the script? or how do I keep an internal timer to predict `max_execution_time`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to register a function to be called at the end of script execution.  You can use this to detect when the script has been terminated and perform a certain set of actions.

Comment: Keep in mind that the shutdown callback will only be called, if the script execution completes. If the user aborts the connection, this does not get called.

Answer (score 7):

[exit()/die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) will stop a php script.

To know when to stop the script, you'll just have to use [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) as a timer and save as a constant (or fetch from the php.ini file) the maximum execution time.

You can also look at the [Connection handling](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) information. Where we have things like [connection_aborted()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) and [connection_status()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php)

But what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

To have a callback at the moment your request is shutting down, use `register_shutdown_function( myfunction )`.

Much like most POSIX environments, PHP also supports [signal handlers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php).  You can register your own handler for the `SIGTERM` event.

```
function my_abort_handler( $signo ) {
   echo "Aborted";
}

pcntl_signal( SIGTERM, "my_abort_handler" );
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [pcntl-alarm](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-alarm.php) which allows a script to send a signal to itself. Also contains some sample on how to catch the kill signals which can be send by the OS. And die() indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could start a `$start=microtime(true)` which will return a timestamp. Then you can just keep checking `microtime(true)` and subtract that from your start time to get the number of seconds since executing.

But no, you can't "catch" the script as its terminating for the reason of the request being too long. You could try to do some last minute stuff in the shutdown handler, but I'm not sure if PHP will honor that.

It looks like there used to be a function that does exactly what you want, [connection_timeout()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.connection-timeout.php), but it was deprecated and removed. Don't know if there is any kind of replacement for this, however.