# ignore_user_abort and redirect in php?

Tags: php, process, background

I have a very similar setup to the person here:
[PHP Background Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265073/php-background-processes)
i.e a very long script that takes up to 10 minutes. However, I need the person who calls the script redirected back to the homepage while the script works. In other words, I need the user experience to be something like this:

- click the update button
- script begins to execute, can take up to 10 minutes
- user is redirected back to the home page immediately

Is this possible using only PHP? I gather I will need

```
ignore_user_abort(true); 
set_time_limit(0);
```

But how do I redirect the user? I can't use javascript because output only gets written to the page at long increments, and I want the redirection to be immediate. Can I use headers? Or will that mess with things?

Alternatively, I could use the cron job approach, but I have zero experience in making a cron job or having it run php code (is that even possible?)

Thanks,
Mala

**Update:**
Using headers to redirect does not work - the page will not load until the script is done. However, eventually the webserver times out and says "Zero-Sized Reply: The requested URL could not be retrieved" (although the script continues running). I guess my only option is to go with the cron job idea. Ick!

Comment: In the link you provided there are some suggestions using exec(). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried several methods and none seems to work, I've even tried to use `register_shutdown_function()` but that also failed. I guess you're stuck with making a cron job.

**I just remembered something (but I haven't tested it), you can try to do something like this:**

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);

ob_start(); // not sure if this is needed

// meta refresh or javascript redirect

ob_flush(); // not sure if this is needed
flush();

// code to process here

exit();
```

Not sure if it'll work but you can try it out.

Comment: Thanks. I want to avoid "soft" redirects if at all possible, so I suppose I'm off to make a cron job! How would you suggest doing it? Have a cron job run a "Script manager" type script, or just directly run the godawful update script?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand you, but before you go into CRON jobs I think you should try Cassy's solution since both method use need the same requirements.

Comment: Also, have you considered AJAX as an option? The user clicks something, a PHP page is processed in the background and upon completion you could have a "job done" message show up on the webpage.

Comment: The ignore_user_abort works only by scripts called from cli. I tried it out by browser called scripts, but browser timeout stopped them.

Comment: @inf3rno: I've used `ignore_user_abort` in non-CLI environments and although it isn't nearly as "responsive", it works.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious solution to me would be splitting the redirect and the background calculation in two separate files and let the redirect script execute the 10-minute script:

**job.php:**

```
<?php
// do the nasty calculation here
```

**redirect.php:**

```
<?php
// start the script and redirect output of the script to nirvana, so that it
// runs in the background
exec ('php /path/to/your/script/job.php >> /dev/null 2>&1 &'); 

// now the redirect
header ('Location /index.php');
```

Assumptions for this to work: You should be on a Linux host with either `safe_mode` disabled or having set the `safe_mode_exec_dir` appropriately. When you're running under windows, the exec string needs to be adapted, while the rest about `safe_mode` remains true.

Notice: When you need to pass arguments to the script, use `escapeshellarg()` before passing it on, see also the [PHP manual on exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation with processing logins.
To keep it short...
I get a PDT, IPN and each sends me a logging email.
An email is sent to client on IPN VERIFIED to give serial number and password to client.
As PDT and IPN I use goto to send me a logging email instead of a bunch of sequential ifs.
On reading many answers I studied each to figure what would suit my isssue.
I finally used...

```
<?php
  ignore_user_abort(TRUE); // at very top
```

As I worked through the progressive checks (no ifs), if they failed I use for example...

```
  $mcalmsg .= "Check [serialnbr]\r\n";
  if (empty($_POST['serialnbr']))
    {    header('Location: '.$returnurl.'?error=1');
      $mcalmsg .= "Missing [serialnbr]\r\n";
      goto mcal_email; // Last process at end of script        
    }
    else
    {$serialnbr=strtoupper(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['serialnbr'])));
     $mcalmsg .= "[serialnbr]=$serialnbr\r\n";
    }
```

This (so far) is working just as needed.
Of course there is more in the script but follows the same concept.
Where this says location, there are also 3 information pages that can each be displyed using the same concept.

```
mcal_email: //last process before ending, always gets here after all else from goto or clearing all checks.
 // compose email and send
?> // end of script
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not try the header approach and see what happens?  You could also try a call to php header method and see if this does the trick.  I would work on trial and error to see what will solve your problem.