# curl timeout less than 1000ms always fails?

Tags: php, curl, connection-timeout

This code always fails (i.e., `$result` is Boolean `false`):

```
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     $curl_version = curl_version();

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 999);

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
```

This code always succeeds (i.e., `$result` is a string containing the header):

```
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     $curl_version = curl_version();

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, 1000);

     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
```

The only difference is that I've changed the timeout from 999ms to 1000ms.

This must be either a bug in curl or some sort of minimum in the documentation for connection timeouts that I missed.  Which is it?  My money is on the latter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> The number of milliseconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely. *If libcurl is built to use the standard system name resolver, that portion of the connect will still use full-second resolution for timeouts **with a minimum timeout allowed of one second***.

Comment: Ok, I saw this in the documentation but I really don't understand what it means and how I can make this to work with a smaller value than 1000. Any help you can give me would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have to compile libcurl for yourself, using `--enable-threaded-resolver` and then compile curl extension for php against it.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of dealing with this would be to set the `CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL` option to 1 in addition to the `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS`. See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL.html for more info.