# programmatically check for CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS before using curl_setopt

Tags: php, curl

I know how to check if classes exists, and functions, but not if an option exists

the option: `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS`

In the documentation it says:

> Added in cURL 7.16.2. Available since PHP 5.2.3.

So, there is an incentive to check before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a constant, so just check if it was defined:

```
if(defined('CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS')) {

}
```

However, even if it defined,  it doesn't mean it will work. See [curl timeout less than 1000ms always fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7987584/258674) for more details.