# How can I execute an external program without php script interrupt

Tags: php, shell

For example:

```
//test.php
#! /usr/local/php/bin/php
<?php
exec('nohup ./loop.php > loop.out');
echo 'I am a superman!';

//loop.php
#! /usr/local/php/bin/php
<?php
$count = 0;
while (true) {
    echo "Loop count:{$count}\n";
    $count++;
}
```

When I run ./test.php I can not get the output 'I am a superman!', as you know loop.php is an endless loop, test.php is interrupted by loop.php, so how can I get the output? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bunch of ways you can achieve this:

Running background process using `&`:

```
exec('nohup ./loop.php > loop.out 2>&1 &');
```

Using `pcntl_fork` and running your process from child:

```
 $pid = pcntl_fork();
 switch ($pid){
   case -1:
     die('Fork failed');
     break;
   case 0:
     exec('nohup ./loop.php > loop.out');
     exit();
   default:
     break;
 }
 echo "I'm not really a superman, just a parent process';
```

There is more ways to do this, just lurk into PHP documentation and questions in [php](/questions/tagged/php) here...

Answer (score 2):

To do asynchronous processes in PHP you would want to use something like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/index.php) or [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/)

Comment: +1 I'm a fan of beanstalkd myself, but the core message is the same: queue it.  Among other things, this lets you easily control the maximum number of simultaneous jobs -- don't run more queue consumers than you can handle.

Comment: I've never heard about beanstalkd, it looks really nice! Updated answer to include a reference to it

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to have a "never ending" loop running. If you need to have a particular task run frequently, consider using Cron Jobs, provided by the Server OS and not actually part of PHP.

Also, if a section of your PHP code needs a lot of time to execute, you should change your design approach to queue the Job on Database and have an external Job Scheduler process it.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265073/php-background-processes) post for more details.

Comment: Cron jobs should be a good way that process tasks frequently, but I just want to run an external program without waiting for it finish. In addition, I want to start the external program by php script logic not a fixed-frequency task.